# Change the color (reverse red and green) in heat map in R

Tags: heatmap

I have made a heat map with these commands:

```
heatmap.data <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", row.names=1) 
heatmap.data_matrix <- data.matrix(heatmap.data)
library(gplots)     
heatmap.2(heatmap.data_matrix, col=redgreen(250), scale="column", key=TRUE, keysize =0.9, symkey=FALSE, 
density.info="none", trace="none", cexRow = 0.5, cexCol = 0.8, margins=c(5,7))
```

As default, I get a heatmap where the positive ratio are in green and negative in red. 
I want to have it vice versa where I see the positive values in red and negative ones in green.
Anyone knows how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to swap the redgreen() function with its friend, greenred().

Without a reproducible code snipplet it is hard to verify, but it should work.

Comment: Great! it was more easier than what I was thinking ;)